Google Forms Custom HTML Styling with two sections, is it possible?
I have created a custom Google Forms UI with tons of questions by following this Video. I painstakingly managed to bind all the questions to radio buttons, check-boxes and text areas with their respective "entry.xxxxxxx" values. I managed to run all that on a custom HTML page.
It all goes swimmingly, I manage to receive the correct answers after clicking my custom page's submit button. However, this only works for the first section of the form. The problem is that the last question of my first section in the original Google Forms determines whether clicking the submit button will lead to the second section of the survey, which has additional questions, or send the answers as they are.
This is where I run into huge problems. No matter what I do, I only receive answers from the first section.
Even if I get myself a pre-filled link with all the answers from the two sections at once, and replace "viewform?usp=pp_url" with "formResponse?", it still sends answers only from the first section. The only possible way to send answers from both sections is doing the form through Google Forms' website, which is not the behavior I am looking for.
EDIT: Forgive me for the hastily written issue, but I am able to submit a minimal reproducible example just now. I cannot give you access to the original Google Form, but I made a new one, which I think encapsulates the problem perfectly.
This is the Google Form. Its third question determines if you will be required to give answers to an additional question. If you pick the first answer, you must answer an additional question, which is in another section.
This is the Docs spreadsheet with the sent answers. You can use it to track the sent answers. As you can see, I somehow managed to submit an answer to the survey bypassing the second section, despite the answer restrictions.
This is a link to my custom website, implementing a custom frontend for the Form. You can test sending answers through it and see them arriving in the Docs document above. What you will notice is, no matter what you do, the additional question's answer is not sent (my problem exactly)... The code looks like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Survey Form</title>
    <style>
        /* Hide the additional question in the beginning */
        #additional-question {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd4yBJhJQSkAk_SqGsmZYFRqLFZbYksrfmSWJhZTb66Ipoi6w/formResponse" method="POST">

        <!-- Question 1 with checkboxes -->
        <h3>Question 1</h3>
        <input type="checkbox" name="entry.593249009" value="Answer 1"> Answer 1<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="entry.593249009" value="Answer 2"> Answer 2<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="entry.593249009" value="Answer 3"> Answer 3<br>

        <!-- Question 2: Open-ended -->
        <h3>Question 2</h3>
        <textarea name="entry.817437226" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Type your answer here..."></textarea><br>

        <!-- Question 3 with radio buttons. If "Answer 1" is picked, an additional question appears. This corresponds to Google Forms' second section with questions. If not, the form must be submitted only with section 1's answers.-->

        <h3>Question 3</h3>
        <input type="radio" name="entry.69082139" id="option1" value="Answer 1 (IF THIS ANSWER IS PICKED, THE SURVEY PROCEEDS TO THE NEXT SECTION WITH ADDITIONAL QUESTIONS. ELSE, THE SURVEY IS SUBMITTED)"> Answer 1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="entry.69082139" value="Answer 2"> Answer 2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="entry.69082139" value="Answer 3"> Answer 3<br>
        <input type="radio" name="entry.69082139" value="Answer 4"> Answer 4<br>
        <input type="radio" name="entry.69082139" value="Answer 5"> Answer 5<br>
        
        <div id="additional-question">
            <!-- Additional Question with checkboxes -->
            <h3>Additional Question</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" name="entry.1107634309" value="Additional Answer 1"> Additional Answer 1<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="entry.1107634309" value="Additional Answer 2"> Additional Answer 2<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="entry.1107634309" value="Additional Answer 3"> Additional Answer 3<br>
        </div>

        <!-- Submit Button -->
        <br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script>
        // Get the elements
        const option1 = document.getElementById('option1');
        const additionalQuestion = document.getElementById('additional-question');

        // Add an event listener for the radio button selection. Make the additional question appear if the first answer of the third question is picked.
        document.querySelectorAll('input[name="entry.69082139"]').forEach(radio => {
            radio.addEventListener('change', function() {
                if (option1.checked) {
                    additionalQuestion.style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    additionalQuestion.style.display = 'none';
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Each checkbox/textbox/radio is mapped through the name and value attributes to the corresponding ones in Google Forms. If you have filled all possible answers, including the additional question, you send out a POST request with all the answers, but for some reason, the second section's answers are omitted.
Why could that be? How can I fix it?

This is really all quite unclear. We don't know how your "custom page" works, how exactly you embedded the form there, etc. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Thank you for your response. I have just added more information and a minimal reproducible example. If you need further clarification, please write again, solving this issue is important for me.

The first page of the Google Form submit a few entry.xyz parameters, and an array named partialResponse. Then on the second page, it submits a few different entry.xyz fields - and the responses from the previous page, appear to have been put into this partialResponse now. Plus there's a few other parameters, that might be necessary. So you will have to make your form submit the same format; might need some additional JavaScript to convert the field values into this structure.

I have trouble seeing a pattern in the partialResponse array, but I think a bigger trouble is the fbzx parameter, which seems to be unique and randomly generated for each submission.
